# How to infer the type of object keys from a string array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following function:

```js
    const infer = (...params: string[]): Record<string, string> => {
      const obj: Record<string, string> = {};
      // Put all params as keys with a random value to obj
      // [...]
      return obj;
    }
```

This function will take n strings and return an object containing exactly those strings as keys, with random values.

So `infer("abc", "def")` might return `{"abc": "1337", "def":"1338"}`.

Is there any way to infer the return type to get complete type-safety from this function? The code of the function guarantees that each key will be present in the returned object and that each value will be a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could declare it like this:

```
const infer = <T extends string[]>(...params: T): Record<T[number], string> => {
  const obj: Record<string, string> = {};
  // Put all params as keys with a random value to obj
  // [...]
  return obj;
};

const t = infer("a", "b", "c") // const t: Record<"a" | "b" | "c", string>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAZgUwE4wLwwDwBUbIAeUyYAJhDNKggOYDaAugHwAUAdJwA4CGqPAWwgAuGLgCUogErJQqMnnpgArgIBGaRgBoqUGmFrNMRgN4AoGDFCRYINQCtpskPOzU6O9waNYTAXwBuCxgAehCYAAVlWB4AG1iYXn4hGB5KAGtkAE9KAHc4KAALVJh+chABGAA3OOVkGCgQGDt7YLCYek52RmDUZChlVDBmhyDAszNraAbMBBRUVgAiHkWdRbVVmEXgRfFQ8KnYKCc5BWXFmAAfLY2rrZ3PPTpmCaA)

Comment: Amazing, can you explain what the `T[number]` part does exactly?

Comment: Sure. If you have `type MyTuple = ["a", "b", "c"]`, you can use the [lookup/index access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to access item types by their numeric index value, e.g.  `MyTuple[0]` has type `"a"`. `number` in `MyTuple[number]` simply stands for all possible numeric index values, so `MyTuple[number]` is the union of all possible item types, which are your desired string values.

Comment: What if I pass the keys in as a single list? How can I get the same output?

Comment: @etarrowo You can drop the rest parameter from `infer` and let `T` extend string, like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAZgUwE4wLwwDwBUbIAeUyYAJhDNKggOYB8AFAA4CGqrAthAFwyrJWZcABsAnjFwBtALoBKPgCVkoVGTwAaKlBpgGmejADeAKBgxQkWCABGAKyUqQa7NTpa3ew1iMBfANxm-MhQAK6oYDC2doEBJpbQMLBYCCiojFIARKyZWpk2uTCZwJnyMAD05TDKqurZmTAAPkUFTUUlHjp09EA)

Comment: awesome thank you @ford04 this one has been puzzling me for a bit

Comment: I wonder whats up with the `reduce` type in my implementation bit . ly/39fXNIf (sorry the tsplayground link is too long)

Comment: @etarrowo I do not open those shortened links, sorry. That seems to be a different question, feel free to open a new one, so all can answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857002/inferring-union-of-array-values-does-not-work-as-expected here is the link to my new question @ford04