# Inferring union of array values does not work as expected

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I was working on a method today that creates a key,value map from two lists of strings. Here is an example:

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const values = ['x', 'y', 'z']
const map = createMap(keys, values)
/*
{
  a: 'x',
  b: 'y',
  c: 'z'
}
*/
```

The implementation I landed on looks like this:

```js
function createMap<T extends string>(
  keys: readonly T[],
  values: readonly string[]
): Record<T, string> {
  if (keys.length !== values.length) {
    throw new Error('Key and Value lists must have same length') 
  }

  return keys.reduce<Record<string, string>>((accumulator, key, index) => {
    if (accumulator.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      throw new Error('Keys must be unique')
    }

    return {
      ...accumulator,
      [key]: values[index]
    }
  }, {})
}
```

And it works, but the type inference has a strange property

When the `key` parameter is a variable that contains an array of strings the result is: `Record<string, string>`, but if you directly pass an array to the `key` param, the result is: `Record<'item1' | 'item2' | 'etc.', string>`. Check out the code below for more details:

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const values = ['x', 'y', 'z']
const map = createMap(keys, values) // type is Record<string, string>
const map = createMap(['a', 'b', 'c'], values) // type is Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>
```

**Can someone explain why it behaves like this?**

Here is a link to this code in a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=25&ssc=23&pln=24&pc=35#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)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be because the type of the `['a', 'b', 'c']` literal is inferred to be the tuple type `['a', 'b', 'c']`, which when used as an array becomes `Array<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>`. In contrast, your `keys` variable is inferred to have type `Array<string>`.

You can achieve the inverse result by explicit type annotations:

```
const keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const values = ['x', 'y', 'z']

const m1 = createMap(keys, values) // => Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>
const m2 = createMap(['a', 'b', 'c'] as string[], values) // => Record<string, string>
```

Comment: Alternative `const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const`. A slightly less repetitive way to get the array to be inferred as a tuple.

Comment: Hmm I see very interesting behavior

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the type of the keys parameter is of type `string[]` and therefore `T` is of type `string` so the return type becomes `Record<string, string>`.

In the second example the keys parameter is a tuple of string literal types.

See the docs about tuples here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple.

See the docs about string literal types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

See the example below for a more explicit view on what is going on:

```js
const keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // Type is tuple of string literal types
const map = createMap(keys, values) // type is Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>
```